# How can I select distinct IDs of table that has not specific value in its sub table?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables with 1-n relationship. One of them is auto services table and the other one has their specifications like;

```
 ID   ServiceId    Name  
---------------------------             
 1     FJ12        Fletcher Jones     
 2     HS35        Hardy's
 3     YK65        Yorker

SpecialityID   ServiceID    Name
---------------------------------
1              FJ12         AUTH
2              FJ12         PRIV
3              FJ12         GRS
4              HS35         PRIV
5              HS35         AUTH
6              HS35         CRS
7              YK65         PRIV
8              HS35         GRS
```

I tried with some left outer join queries and where clauses but I couldn't handle. How can I get all auto services from first table which doesn't have 'AUTH' specification in second table ? (second table is first table's sub table)

Comment: Why have you tagged 2 different RDBMS? Please only tag the RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: I would use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

Comment: Could you also post your attempts please? You say you've tried, so it's helpful to the volunteers if you provide us with those attempts. Expected results would also be great (but `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, as Dan said, or a `LEFT JOIN` seem to be the right solutions). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select aus.*
from auto_services aus
where not exists (select 1
                  from specifications s
                  where s.serviceId = aus.serviceId and
                        s.name = 'AUTH'
                 );
```

For performance, you want in index on `specifications(serviceId, name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query using joins -

```
SELECT 
F1.ServiceId,
F2.Name
from            table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON              t1.serviceid=t2.serviceid 
WHERE           t2.NAME <> 'AUTH';
```

using Exists

```
SELECT t1.serviceid, 
       t2.NAME 
FROM   table1 t1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT serviceid, 
                      NAME 
               FROM   table2 t2 
               WHERE  t1.serviceid = t2.serviceid 
                      AND t2.NAME <> 'AUTH')
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select distinct serviceid from specialities where name = 'AUTH'
```

returns all the `distinct serviceid`s from the table `specialities` that have 'AUTH' in the `name` column.
So all you have is to exclude these `serviceid`s from the `auto_services` table, 
with a `left join` like this:

```
select * from auto_services a left join (
  select distinct serviceid from specialities where name = 'AUTH'
) s on s.serviceid = a.serviceid
where s.serviceid is null
```

or with `not in`:

```
select * from auto_services 
where serviceid not in (
  select distinct serviceid from specialities where name = 'AUTH'
)
```